# Using threads for Discord bot commands (Discord.py Slash commands)

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py

im currently making a discord bot in Python using Discord.py library, however I am facing the problem of using threads to prevent the bot from going down during the time it is performing a function requested by a user. In fact, some "slash-commands" require the execution of some functions that take several minutes to execute, but I can't find a way to integrate the use of threads while still managing to send a confirmation of execution to the user at the end.

```
    # TEST COMMAND
    @bot.tree.command(name="test_command", description="Just a test")
    @app_commands.describe( things = "nice parameter")
    async def userTestEvent(interaction: discord.Interaction,things: str):

        await interaction.response.defer()
        # I run the function which takes 5+ minutes
        result = clientFunction(things)
        # I complete the bot's response with the result of the function
        await interaction.followup.send(interaction.user.mention + " , " + result)
```

This is an example of a "slash command" which requires the execution of a function that takes a long time to execute. I have already tried also executing it in a separate thread and passing it the "interaction" object as a parameter so as to execute the interaction.followup.send() at the end of the execution, but this last method is not executed correctly (probably because in that instant the execution of the parent function ("userTestEvent") already finished and that object no longer exists?).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could fix this? Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your question sounds pretty confusing to me... On a sidenote: NOTHING should take that long to execute, may be worth to look at the code as well.

Comment: Two important points. 1 - You must respond to an interaction within 3 seconds or defer it to respond later. 2 - You shouldn't have a function that takes a long time and blocks the execution of your bot because it is entirely synchronous. You should study ways to develop your function in an asynchronous context. If you are using `requests`, replace it with `aiohttp`. If you are using `time.sleep()`, replace it with `await asyncio.sleep()`...

Comment: @Hazzu Thanks, I hadn't yet learned to use "async" and "await" and for this reason the function that took so long to run was entirely synchronous, blocking the whole bot. Now I made it asynchronous and it works fine